# XSL-FO external-graphic not showing

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I'm having some issues getting the external-graphic to show in my PDF. I've tried using all sorts of paths using the `url()` but nothing seems to work. Is it something else I'm missing?

```
<fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block>
        <fo:external-graphic src="url(ss/naam.png)"></fo:external-graphic>
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Comment: Does it work if you add single quotes? I.e., `src="url('ss/naam.png')"`.

Comment: Strangely enough it didn't, we just went around it by uploading the images and passing the URL instead.

Comment: @KevinPeters thanks for your answer, could you explain us a bit more about how was the solution you mentioned? how about upload the images? you mean from a web server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using Apache FOP 1.1 Ver.

first you should tell apache FOP that where is base path in follwing way.
You should copy code as it is.

```
    fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
    // for image base URL : images from Resource path of project
    String serverPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    fopFactory.setBaseURL(serverPath);
    // for fonts base URL :  .ttf from Resource path of project
    fopFactory.getFontManager().setFontBaseURL(serverPath);
```

In your XSL template file

```
<fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block>
        <fo:external-graphic src="url(resources/naam.png)"></fo:external-graphic>
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

**Here naam.png will be in resources/ directory**

I added all images and required font font files in resource director of my project.
It is working fine for me.
Thank you

Comment: Even after doing this image is not appearing nor any exception is thrown in the webapp,image is shown when it is simple java application

Comment: What works instantly is  src="images/fop.jpg" here you can give complete file path , please look into https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fo/align2.fo

Comment: where does "request.getSession()" i get an error in request

Answer (score 4):

To add a `<fo:external-graphic>` for an absolute path the only way it worked for me is to write the url as `url(file:/C:/myPath/image.jpg)`. [Source](https://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/topic17516.html#p49546).

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url(file:/C:/myPath/image.jpg)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<fo:external-graphic src="ss/naam.png"/>
```

Works for me this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a variable, this might help:

```
</fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="5"
                                        border="0.1pt solid gray"  
                                        padding="5pt">
                                         <fo:block>
                                            <fo:external-graphic 
                                            display-align="center"
                                            content-width="338px"
                                            content-height="290px"
                                            src="url(file:/{$screenshot-path})">
                                            </fo:external-graphic>
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
```

Answer (score 0):

A processor-specific note. The XSL-FO standard specifies that `uri-specification` must look like `url(...)` where the content may optionally be placed in quotes, but at least in Apache FOP this does not work. What works in Apache FOP is a plain path relative to the FO file:

```
<external-graphic src="../res/pic-1.png" />
```

This is what they use in [their samples](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/examples.html).

Answer (score -1):

Example, it runs in my xls-fo template for Apache FOP.

```
<fo:external-graphic src='url("src/main/resources/ima/logo.depo.gif")' />
```

Comment: This will only work locally in an IDE but not when it's deployed in a separate application container. Once the app is built, the src/main/ folder won't exist.