# Insert an image in FOP / XSL-FO

Tags: java, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I want so use an image in the header of my XSL-FO File:

```
 <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
            <fo:block text-align="center" line-height="40pt" start-indent = "10.0cm">
               <fo:external-graphic height="auto" width="auto" content-height="auto"
                        content-width="auto" src="url('PDF/logo.png')">
              </fo:external-graphic>        
            </fo:block>
 </fo:static-content>
```

But I get the error, that the file format is not supported.
I tried with png, bmp, gif, jpg, jpeg and everytime I get the same error.

```
Jul 15, 2014 8:01:26 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
Schwerwiegend: Image not available. URI: PDF/logo.png. Reason: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found for PDF/logo.png (See position 13:119)
org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found for PDF/logo.png.........
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Sincerely Niko

Comment: This is related to initialization of FOP context. [Post here explains more on it.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267951/xsl-fo-external-graphic-not-showing

Comment: I do not think so. Are you sure that your file (so called logo.png) is actually a PNG image? Check it and see what it is actually, I will bet it is not a PNG.

Comment: What does it mean ... you tried " png,bmp,gif,jpg,jpeg"? You tried what? Where?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this using the correct `URI` for `src`:

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:external-graphic  src="url(file:///D:/logo.png)" />
</fo:block>
```

Read the specification `XSL`:
https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/

`URI` definition:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme