# Is there any way to solve XSLT Images not showing up when running JAR in Unix environment

Tags: java, unix, xslt

I am currently working on a project that automates the process of generating Letters.

We are using XSLT to style the xml information into our letter.

The program itself is written in Java and run as a jar on Unix. Everything runs fine in Eclipse and even runs without error on Unix.

However, for some reason when we run on Unix, the images don't show up.

We currently use the line of code:

```
src="url('test.png')"
```

but have also tried:

```
url(file:///u/project/styles/test.png)
```

```xsl
         <fo:block padding-top="-2mm" text-align="left">
                  <fo:external-graphic
                  content-width="scale-to-fit" 
                  content-height="73%"
                  scaling="uniform"
                  src="url('test.png')" />
         </fo:block>
```

I am just trying to get the image to show up once run in Unix.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267951/xsl-fo-external-graphic-not-showing

Comment: Thank you for the response. We are trying some of the solutions from this poost and a few others. I'll post if anything works.